# Bootstrap 5 Nuxt dynamic components not working

Tags: javascript, css, nuxt.js, bootstrap-5

I am trying to implement Bootstrap 5 into my `Nuxt project`.

The styles work fine but anything that used-to use `jQuery` doesn't work.

**My installation process:**

1. Download files from the [Bootstrap download page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/)
2. Create `/css` and `/js` folders and move into asset folder
3. Put `bootstrap.css` into `/css` folder and `bootstrap.min.js` into `/js` folder
4. Add configuration to the `nuxt.config.js` file:

```js
css: [
   '@/assets/css/bootstrap.css'
],

js: [
   '@/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js'
],
```

5. Refresh the site a dozen times.

This is the code I am testing taken straight from the Bootstrap component site:

```html
// index.vue
<div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown button
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This one may be interesting to follow as of an official support from the `bootstrap-vue` module (that can directly be used with Nuxt): https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/5507

Comment: Unfortunatley, it's going to be a while before they release BootstrapVue / BS5 version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of editing your nuxt.config.js file - Try this:

1. In layouts/default.vue add the code below to the script section
2. Place the bootstrap 5 minified js and css bundle files at /static/bootstrap

```
<script>

export default {
  data () {
    return {

    }
  },

  head () {
    return {
      title: 'Test Page - My awesome project',
      link: [
        { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css' }
      ],
      script: [
        { src: "/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js", type: "text/javascript"}
      ]

    }
  }


}
</script>
```

Comment: not working on bootstrap 5